# ASP.Net Using POST with Server.Execute

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to do something like

```
Server.Execute("page1.aspx");
```

but I need to pass POST data to this page.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Since Server.Execute only takes in 3 params, and none of these are anything to do with POST data.

**Solution: 7 Hours Later...**

Unfortunately, the only way I was able to do this was to pass the parameters in the query string (using a GET request). I've searched the web for a while now, and finally felt this was good enough for my application. I tested, and somehow the GET URL size limit of 4K chars does not hold good in this context.

I was able to successfully execute a Server.Execute method with 640K+ chars to another page, and it worked beautifully.

```
Server.Execute("~/pageB.aspx?foo=" + new string('x', 640000));
```

In pageB: Page_Load();

```
Response.Write(Request["foo"].ToString().Length());
```

Result: 640000

So I guess this will have to do for now.

I was afraid of having to send large parameters in the query string, but since it works, who am I to complain! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is using `Server.Execute()` absolutely necessary?

If not, to get page A to post to page B, you could set page A's `.PostBackURL` to page B, then in page B check if `(this.PreviousPage != null)`; if it's not null, then in page B you can use something like  `this.PreviousPage.FindControl()` or `((PageA)this.PreviousPage).txtFirstName.Text` to get at the input values.

If some values aren't directly user-input, you could still assign the values to hidden controls, and make those hidden controls public properties of page A so that page B can access them after casting `.PreviousPage` to `PageA`.

If you don't want to require type-safe references to a specific sending class or interface, the simplest alternative would probably be to use something like this [technique to encapsulate values in Context.Items](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2003061901&page=2):

```
// to store in sending page:
Context.Items("UserName") = UserName.text;
// then call server.Transfer...

// to retrieve in receiving page:
string userName = (string)Context.Items("UserName");
```

Comment: I need PageB to be transparent of what method was used to call it. Also, I can't use AJAX, since this page will be run on a browser that doesn't support javascript. Further, I can't use WebClient / HttpWebRequest because I want PageA's session / authentication / etc to be passed on to PageB

Comment: @Shiroy: In that scenario then, it's probably best to set session variables in page A, then look them up in page B. In any case where the sending page *knows* the results will be consumed by the receiving page, this strategy can work: Create a session dictionary keyed by a "post id". In page A, create/set the post id, and create dictionary entries for each variable, then redirect to page B with the post ID in the query string.

Comment: Creating a Session dictionary could be risky, especially if there are multiple calls to the same page. For instance, if PageA calls PageB 5 times with different parameters. Also, there's no point in burdening the Session with all that extra overhead.

Comment: I understand your aversion to Session objects, so I added a solution based on Context.Items and a link to a pretty straightforward article on it. Hope this helps!